# ORM Kohana Pagination VS total records found

Tags: php, kohana

I'm having some problem with this script... works fine, but not for the total of records found on the query.

I have this function on my ORM called "mix".  There are 3 tables: mixes, generos and mixes_generos.

I can search in the table "mixes" or on the table "generos", anyone.

```
public function search($query, $itemsperpage, $page)
{
    if (empty($page))
        $page = 1;

    $offset = ($page - 1) * $itemsperpage;

    $orm = $this->join('mixes_generos', 'LEFT')->on('mix.id', '=', 'mixes_generos.mix_id')
                ->join('generos', 'LEFT')->on('generos.id', '=', 'mixes_generos.genero_id')
                ->where_open()
                    ->or_where('mix.nombre', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
                    ->or_where('mix.descripcion', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
                    ->or_where('generos.nombre', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->where_close()
                ->and_where('mix.estatus', '=', 'active')
                ->order_by('mix.fecha_produccion', 'DESC')
                ->order_by('mix.track', 'DESC');

    $this->_search_total = $orm->reset(FALSE)->count_all();

    $orm = $orm->limit($itemsperpage)->offset($offset);

    return $orm;
}

public function search_total()
{
    return $this->_search_total;
}
```

Then, in my controller i have this:

```
$data = ORM::factory('mix')->search('pop music', 10, 1);
```

if I want to echo the total, i do this:

```
echo $data->search_total();
```

in my view I print the info:

```
foreach($data->find_all() as $mix)
    echo $mix->nombre;
```

http://s10.postimage.org/cvnr28nop/records.jpg

in this link you will see the result, look closely the column "records_founds" vs the number of "records" that it founds, 3 vs 1??.

And that is the main problem... because when i print the data of the mixes shows 3 instead 1.  I also add an group_by('mix.id') and nothing :(

What do you think?

Thank you

Comment: I dont understand your problem. Does ORM made wrong query?

Comment: I don't know @biakaveron.  Did you see the image link in my main post? did you see the total of "records_found" VS the only register that it's show?  How is that possible... maybe in the new version of Kohana 3.3 fixed that, but, I don't tested yet... btw, how do I implement two more ORM's? I know about "with" but, honestly, I don't understand that... so, for that reason I made this function, maybe you can give me more light about that.  Thank you.